# WRL Project Template not found for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to follow [these steps on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973463.aspx) for building a WRL-based C++ WinRT component.  However in step #3, I am unable to find anything related to WRL in the results:

- *In the Search online templates box in the upper right corner, type
  WRL Class Library. When the template appears in the search results,
  choose the OK button)*

How can I get the WRL Project Template for Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: The [template on the VS Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/346e6fbc-6508-43c8-af7f-9a922bb57128) has now been updated and is now available for Visual Studio 2013 as well.

---

It seems the WRL Project Template for Visual Studio has not yet been updated for Visual Studio 2013.  There is a workaround however:

1. Instead of acquiring the project template from VS2013, download it through the website.  [WRL Class Library](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/346e6fbc-6508-43c8-af7f-9a922bb57128).
2. The downloaded file would be called WRLVSIXProject.vsix.
3. Change the file extension.  Rename it to WRLVSIXProject.zip
4. Unzip the zip file.
5. Open the file extension.vsixmanifest in a text editor
6. In the  section, insert the following line after the first line:

   ```
   <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="12.0" />
   ```
7. Save the file and close it
8. Zip all the contents of this folder back to a file called WRLVSIXProject.zip
9. Rename the file back to WRLVSIXProject.vsix
10. Double click on the file.  It will now provide an option to install this project template for Visual Studio 2013
11. Install and proceed
12. Now when you do "File -> New Project" in VS2013, you will see an option called "WRLClassLibrary" under Visual C++ > Windows Store