# WRL Project Template not found for Visual Studio 2013 again

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wrl

I'm trying to check out WRL and is having the same problem as indicated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752965/wrl-project-template-not-found-for-visual-studio-2013) thread where I can't find the WRL project template using Visual Studio 2013. I clicked the links in the answer in the thread but the visual studio gallery is saying that "This item is not yet published.". By the way I tried commenting, on the answer on the thread but I don't have enough reputation so I just started another one.